# A few questions about JavaScript basics - $, "is not a function"

Tags: javascript, jquery

Being fully self-taught without actually reading up on JavaScript (It's my job now, believe it or not) there are a few things I accept but don't understand.

The first one is the dollar sign.

As far as I use understand it, it's a shortcut to `document.getElementById()`,
but if I log `$` and `document.getElementById()` to console - Only `$` returns a value. This value however is always `function()`, shouldn't it be. The element? What gives?

The second issue I have is something that keeps coming up in my code and I go out of my way to change the code to eliminate it. It's the "... is not a function" error.

For example:

```
if ($.inArray($(div_id).val(), arr) >= 0);
```

Will give the error `.val() is not a function`. Why? And how do I use the value of `div_id` to see if it's in array?

Comment: And this is why jquery is dangerous :)

Comment: @annakata, this is why any API is dangerous ;)

Comment: @eyelidlessness this is why the almost religious propagation of jquery as a javascript de facto standard is dangerous.

Comment: Considering how disturbingly hard the standard JS API is to find and how effective jQuery is in most cases - It's hard to avoid the situation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hiya. When you're using Jquery (which I assume you are), then $ will return the jquery object.  This can contain an array of matched HTML elements depending on the selector you used. For example $("#foo") will return the jquery object containing the element with id foo. You can get the actual HTML DOM element out using $("#foo")[0] - using the array-style notation.

Can you give us some more info on what you're trying to achieve with the $.inArray example?

Comment: jQuery doesn't alias `$` to `document.getElementById`, it aliases `$` to its CSS selector query engine (which used to be internal, and now uses Sizzle). Using `$` as an alias to `document.getElementById` is probably a hint that the questioner is using either Prototype or Mootools or a similar library (these actually do more than select the element with that id, for that matter).

Comment: @eyelidlessness: Actually, jQuery it aliases `$` to `jQuery`, which is a function that does more than just use the selector engine, depending on what you pass into it.

Comment: @T.J. Crowder, that's correct. I was being overly concise due to comment character limi…

Comment: Yes it is jQuery, the confusion with getElementById is based on a short and rather ignorant search for an answer. Having no "fundamental" training, I treat jQuery and JS roughly as the same thing as they're what I work with. What I'm trying to achieve is to find a match between a value in a selection list and an array (Which currently looks horrid due to trying to fit in JSON objects into it....)

Comment: To be more specific - I'm gathering up data from markers placed on a google map in an array (Which I'm struggling with) as it needs location name, an id, latitude, longitude and a category, I then need to compare the selected name (id) with the markers in the array.

Answer (score 2):

$ is a valid variable name.

So if you try to use $ without setting it, it will not work.

A lot of people/frameworks however use $ as a shortcut to document.getElementById, they would declare it at the top of the script as:

```
function $(id) { return document.getElementById(id); }
```

Answer (score 0):

$ and document.getElementById is not one of the same thing. $ gives you a function in console only when you are using some library like jquery which mapes $ to a function.

.val id primarly used to get value of the form elements and that is a jquery function. I think you need to learn more around javascript and jQuery

Answer (score 0):

Neither Javascript nor the DOM define `$`, which (as other answerers said) is often defined in general-purpose DOM libraries like jQuery, Prototype or Mootools. Based on the particular code you included, I suspect you've been coding against the jQuery API (because you use `$.inArray`, see http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/; though your claim that `$` aliases `document.getElementById` confuses matters, as jQuery expects CSS selectors rather than element IDs).

When `$` is expected but undefined, that usually means you'll need to include the library whose API you're using in the HTML document.